# PHP - Replace Word in String (while ignore HTML tags)

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a string with HTML tags, `$paragraph`:

```
$paragraph = '
    <p class="instruction">
        <sup id="num1" class="s">80</sup>
        Hello there and welcome to Stackoverflow! You are welcome indeed.
    </p>
';

$replaceIndex = array(0, 4);
$word = 'dingo';
```

I'd like to replace the words at indices defined by `$replaceIndex` (0 and 4) of `$paragraph`. By this, I mean I want to replace the words "80" and "welcome" (only the first instance) with `$word`. The paragraph itself may be formatted with different HTML tags in different places.

Is there a way to locate and replace certain words of the string while virtually ignoring (but not stripping) HTML tags?

Thanks!

Edit: Words are separated by (multiple) tags and (multiple) whitespace characters, while not including anything within the tags.

Comment: And what makes 80 be at 0th index and welcome at 4th?

Comment: Do these ("80" and "welcome") appear multiple times? If not that should be easy with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Can you tell us what the criteria used here to select words at the index  0 and 4, is it something like it must be preceded by a space and followed by a space or something like that.

Comment: @urban: Yes, words may appear multiple times.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: Words are separated by (multiple) tags or (multiple) whitespace characters, and do not include anything within tags. *I think they're called whitespace characters… spaces, newlines, tabs, etc)

Comment: @hamism: See my comment to Hanky웃Panky above. Thanks!

Comment: @Pixelsage yes they are called whitespace characters and represented by ``\s``

Comment: @Pixelsage I don't think there is a bullet-proof way to do this. I would go with matching context and [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) but see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3727050) why it is a bad idea...

Comment: @urban: Is it possible to explode `$paragraph` into an array of tags and words, and somehow locate word number `$replaceIndex[$i]` in the array? Then reconstruct $paragraph by imploding it all back together? Did that even make any sense? Unfortunately, regex is confusing enough for me that I don't know how to do such things.

Comment: Posted an answer using the method I suggested in the above comment! Looks to me like everything works fine.

Comment: Must read: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2729937 (kinda related).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the tips. I figured it out! Since I'm new to PHP, I'd appreciate it if any PHP veterans have any tips on simplifying the code. Thanks!

```
$paragraph = '
    <p class="instruction">
        <sup id="num1" class="s">80</sup>
        Hello there and welcome to Stackoverflow! You are welcome indeed.
    </p>
';

// Split up $paragraph into an array of tags and words
$paragraphArray = preg_split('/(<.*?>)|\s/', $paragraph, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$wordIndicies = array(0, 4);
$replaceWith = 'REPLACED';

foreach ($wordIndicies as $wordIndex) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $wordIndex; $i++) {
        // if this element starts with '<', element is a tag.
        if ($paragraphArray[$i]{0} == '<') {
            // push wordIndex forward to compensate for found tag element
            $wordIndex++;
        }
        // when we reach the word we want, replace it!
        elseif ($i == $wordIndex) {
            $paragraphArray[$i] = $replaceWith;
        }
    }
}

// Put the string back together
$newParagraph = implode(' ', $paragraphArray);

// Test output!
echo(htmlspecialchars($newParagraph));
```

*Only caveat is that this may potentially produce unwanted spaces in $newParagraph, but I'll see if that actually causes any issues when I implement the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\b80\b|\bwelcome\b/', $word, $paragraph);
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: A commenter helped me clarify: words may appear multiple times, and I am only trying to replace a certain instance of it. I am interested in replacing words at specified indices, not predefined words. But thanks for your answer!

Comment: For that, you need to define $NUMBER and $WORD in your string which you want to replace. Regex can do it.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML could come in handy as well:

```
$paragraph = '
    <p class="instruction">
        <sup id="num1" class="s">80</sup>
        Hello there and welcome to Stackoverflow! You are welcome indeed.
    </p>
';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($paragraph);
$xml->sup = $word;
```